# How do I specify columns in the searchPanes extension for DT::datatables in R?

Tags: shiny, datatables, dt

I'm unable to specify which columns should be included in the `searchPanes` extension in `datatables`. Here's a minimum example:

```
library(DT)
DT::datatable(
  mtcars,
  rownames   = FALSE,
  selection  = "none",
  class      = "cell-border stripe",
  extensions = c("SearchPanes", "Select"),
  options    = list(
    columnDefs = list(list(
      searchPanes = list(show = TRUE)
    )),
    dom         = 'P'
  )
)
```

In this example, searchPanes is deciding which columns to show (cyl, vs, am, gear, carb):

[image]

But if I just want to have panes for `cyl` and `vs` and specify the `targets` option:

```
library(DT)
DT::datatable(
  mtcars,
  rownames   = FALSE,
  selection  = "none",
  class      = "cell-border stripe",
  extensions = c("SearchPanes", "Select"),
  options    = list(
    columnDefs = list(list(
      searchPanes = list(show = TRUE),
      targets = c(2, 8)
    )),
    dom         = 'P'
  )
)
```

It's still showing all the panes as before, but now also includes disp:

[image]

Do do I get it to only show panes for columns I specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered on github:
https://github.com/rstudio/DT/pull/756#issuecomment-612486686

In short, `targets` is applied inclusively or exclusively depending on the the value of `show`, which will determine which columns are hidden or shown in the search panes.